# How to have python waiting for input until input unchanged for a certain time

Tags: python, input, speech-recognition

My overall objective is to enter the output of speech recognition software into Python as strings. The speech recognition software types what it hears into whatever field is open in real-time. It is not possible to get the output any other way. Sentences are separated by several seconds of silence, during which the speech recognition software will not type anything. I would like each sentence to be a separate string in Python.

Therefore , what I would like to do is to have my script constantly listening for input, and whenever the current input does not change for a fixed amount of time, save the current input in a string and listen for new input.

Something like:

```
    While true:
        start timer
        While timer <= t: 
            Listen for input
            if input changes: set timer to 0
        save input to string
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this or have a better way of accomplishing my objective? Many thanks!

Comment: What graphical toolkit (the thing that provides access to the text field) are you using? Or will the speech recognition software be typing into a console? (And in the latter case which OS?)

Comment: Hi david, I was planning on just using the console, which unfortunately has to be Windows, but I'm open to any other packages or libraries that would make this goal easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do multi-threading. Threads allow you do some tasks simultaneously. I suggest you do the input-fetching operation as a thread and a timer operation on another thread. So now, you can check the timer while fetching the input and pause/resume the fetch when the timer reaches a particular limit.
In case you need references on multi-threading: [Multi-Threading tutorial in tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Comment: Thank you , i'm looking into this now. To check, is it possible to reset the timer in one thread based on whether or not there is input in the other thread?

Comment: @MichieldeJong Yes. Though each thread is like a separate process, they share the same memory space. There is a  class called [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) in python which is often used for inter-thread communication.